# Code to tweet a post from a specific Twitter account when published?

Tags: twitter, blogs, publish, tweets

I run a community blog and was wondering if there is a code I could add to my authors' posts that automatically publishes their posts to their blog Twitter account? (I've made Twitter accounts for everyone on the blog).

So say for example, if an author called John publishes a post, the code I want would be included in his bio section in the post footer and would automatically tweet his new post from his @BLOGJohn account.

I have the author-specific bios already made. I'm on a Google Blogger platform.

Comment: Twitter has recently completely changed it's api to require OAuth.  This will be more work than you would think.

Comment: Is it possible though? I have no experience with Twitter API at all.

Answer (score 0):

Although this used to be pretty straightforward, twitter has locked down it's api interaction pretty tightly.  Using a third party service that has access to your blog and twitter account is going to be the best solution.  Try twitterfeed.

http://twitterfeed.com/

Comment: That requires each author having a RSS feed, which I don't have. I could use labels, but that will mess around with my "related posts" section of the site.